# Most Efficient way to Round Corners iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, calayer

Now I know theres different ways to round corners but what way is most efficient?

the layer route:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

or some sort of coregraphics route:

```
void roundTheRect(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, float ovalWidth, float ovalHeight)
{
    float fw, fh;
    if (ovalWidth == 0 || ovalHeight == 0) {
        CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
        return;
    }
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
    fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;
    fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fw, fh/2);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 1);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 1);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: I've never had to set shouldRasterize to get rounded corners.

Comment: shouldRasterize is to keep the views from lagging not to create rounded corners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always work at the highest level possible, sometimes working low level just isn't worth it. `view.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;`
works great for any `UIView`

Comment: thanks! Makes sense to always work at the highest level now that I think about it! Do you know of any documents that talk about efficiency in objc?

Comment: To be honest I don't know if there is any good documentation on memory management just yet since Apple just recently introduced ARC(Automatic Reference Counting) which changed how we manage our objects. If you're new to iOS you'll quickly learn that Apple documentation is for the most part pretty subpar. Apple does however offer great built-in tools for monitoring the efficiency of your app.

Comment: @DanZimm, there are some really good videos about it from WWDC 2011, one covers exactly this. There are definitely times when you want to use core graphics because using `view.layer.cornerRadius` requires blending which is relatively slow on the iPhone. pob21 is right though, use the highest level API unless that does not work well in your circumstance.